# I want set `amount` to `-1` if not existed, and next step compare with `-1`

Tags: mysql, database

I have these records:

```
Order
----------
id   amount
1    10
2    NULL
3    20
```

I want set `amount` to `-1` if not existed, and next step compare with `-1`.

I write this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    COALESCE(o.amount, -1) AS amount2
FROM Order o
WHERE amount2 = -1
```

but return this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'amount2' in 'where clause'
```

I like to return this:

```
Order
----------
id   amount2
2    -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  COALESCE(o.amount, -1) AS amount2
FROM Order o
WHERE COALESCE(o.amount, -1) = -1
```

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column

Quoted from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 0):

I think,

SELECT id,amount2 FROM (SELECT id, COALESCE(amount, -1)amount2 FROM order)n WHERE n.amount2=-1

Good look!